# Turn off or disable inbound requests on TCP on DNS Server

Tags: dns, bind

Is there a possibility to turn off/disable  TCP in DNS Server, so that it would reject incoming TCP requests?

I would want the request coming to DNS Server and then getting rejected in DNS Server.

Is there a easy way to turn off or Turn on whenever required?

This is just for testing purposes. The DNS server is not on public domain

my named.conf looks like this

```
options {

        # The directory statement defines the name server's working directory

        directory "/var/lib/named";

        # enable DNSSEC validation
        #
        # If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired, you
        # will need to update your keys. See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        #
        # dnssec-enable yes (default), indicates that a secure DNS service
        # is being used which may be one, or more, of TSIG
        # (for securing zone transfers or DDNS updates), SIG(0)
        # (for securing DDNS updates) or DNSSEC.

        #dnssec-enable yes;

        # dnssec-validation yes (default), indicates that a resolver
        # (a caching or caching-only name server) will attempt to validate
        # replies from DNSSEC enabled (signed) zones. To perform this task
        # the server also needs either a valid trusted-keys clause
        # (containing one or more trusted-anchors or a managed-keys clause.

        #dnssec-validation auto;
        managed-keys-directory "/var/lib/named/dyn/";

        # Write dump and statistics file to the log subdirectory.  The
        # pathenames are relative to the chroot jail.

        dump-file "/var/log/named_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/log/named.stats";

        # The forwarders record contains a list of servers to which queries
        # should be forwarded.  Enable this line and modify the IP address to
        # your provider's name server.  Up to three servers may be listed.

        #forwarders { 192.0.2.1; 192.0.2.2; };

        # Enable the next entry to prefer usage of the name server declared in
        # the forwarders section.

        #forward first;

        # The listen-on record contains a list of local network interfaces to
        # listen on.  Optionally the port can be specified.  Default is to
        # listen on all interfaces found on your system.  The default port is
        # 53.

        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };

        # The listen-on-v6 record enables or disables listening on IPv6
        # interfaces.  Allowed values are 'any' and 'none' or a list of
        # addresses.

        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        # The next three statements may be needed if a firewall stands between
        # the local server and the internet.

        #query-source address * port 53;
        #transfer-source * port 53;
        #notify-source * port 53;

        # The allow-query record contains a list of networks or IP addresses
        # to accept and deny queries from. The default is to allow queries
        # from all hosts.

        #allow-query { 127.0.0.1; };

        # If notify is set to yes (default), notify messages are sent to other
        # name servers when the the zone data is changed.  Instead of setting
        # a global 'notify' statement in the 'options' section, a separate
        # 'notify' can be added to each zone definition.

        notify no;

    disable-empty-zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA";
};
```

Comment: Setup a suitable firewall role. See also [When do DNS queries use TCP instead of UDP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/404840/when-do-dns-queries-use-tcp-instead-of-udp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your firewall to prevent tcp packet from reaching your dns server.

According to this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/181956/is-it-true-that-a-nameserver-have-to-answer-queries-over-tcp) DNS implementation has to support both protocol to be rfc compliant. 
Nonetheless as I said you can configure your firewall to do so, but your DNS could miss some request.

Comment: Indeed. "The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is used when the response data size exceeds 512 bytes, or for tasks such as zone transfers."